# .htaccess mask original url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this URL:

```
localhost:1001/project/index.html
```

And if I write this URL:

```
localhost:1001/project/index.html.twig
```

I want it to be masked to the first one (`localhost:1001/project.index.html`) but the URL processed must be the second one (don't know if it is possible).

I have tried all of this but I think all is wrong in my `.htaccess` in project folder root, because nothing worked as I want:

a)

```
RedirectMatch 302 /project/index.html.twig /project/index.html
```

b)

```
RedirectMatch 301 /project/index.html.twig /project/index.html
```

c)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/project/index.html.twig$ [NC]
RewriteRule /project/index.html [R=301,L]
```

**COMMENTS**

Process I want to obtain:

1. I write in the browser: `localhost:1001/project/index.html.twig`
2. Somehow I want my `.htaccess` to convert that URL in the browser to `localhost:1001/project/index.html` and see that URL in the browser
3. Internally after that I want to process the original URL: `localhost:1001/project/index.html.twig`

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself? In the first part you state: "... masked to the first one (`localhost:1001/project.index.html`) but the URL processed must be the second one" - Ok, that is certainly possible and achieved with an _internal rewrite_. However, in your comments you state: "2. I want my `.htaccess` to convert that URL in the browser to `localhost:1001/project/index.html` and see that URL in the browser" - this is the opposite of what you stated earlier, nothing is masked. This is an _external redirect_. But this then makes "3." impossible.?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for if you want an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project/index\.html$ /project/index.html.trig [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?project/index\.html\.twig$ /project/index.html [END]
```

In case you want an internal rewrite use that variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?project/index\.html\.twig$ /project/index.html [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?project/index\.html$ /project/index.html.trig [END]
```

These rules should work likewise, in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). You should definitely prefer the first option if you have access to it. If you need to use a dynamic configuration file then take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive a server internal error (http status 500) using that rule chances are that you operate an old version of the apache http server. You will find a definite hint on an unknown `[END]` flag in the http servers error log file in that case. Try using the older `[L]` flag in that case, it will probably work the same here, though that depends on your setup.

Comment: Your answer works but i think I didn´t explain, if i write in the browser localhost:1001/project/index.html.twig I want to change it via .htaccess to localhost:1001/project/index.html but the url processed must be the first I wrote,with your solution it redirects to /project/index.html but in the browser still shows /project/index.html.twig

Comment: You confuse the terms "redirect" and "rewrite", you contradict yourself. To "redirect" means that the URL in the browser is changed and a new request to the changed URL is performed. To "rewrite" means the URL in the browser stays the same, but the server internally maps the request to the new target. The rule given above does _not_ redirect, but rewrite, as you requested in your question. If that is not what you see then your are most likely looking at a cached result. Please try again in an anonymous browser window. Or take the time to clearly state what you actually want. Thanks.